# Faster loading times using PHP with a REST API

Tags: php, api, rest

Is there a method that's faster than using PHP with a REST API? I currently have the following set up, using the Eventbrite API:

```
<?php
    $token = ''; // Personal OAuth token
    $eventbrite_url = 'https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/users/me/owned_events/?order_by=start_asc&status=live&show_series_parent=true&token=' . $token;
    $eventbrite_json = json_decode(file_get_contents($eventbrite_url), true);   
?>
```

Then I loop through the JSON:

```
<?php foreach ($eventbrite_json['events'] as $event) : ?>
```

However it's taking a long time to load. I thought about using JS but wouldn't that effectively be doing the same thing? I wasn't sure if the way I am implementing this is wrong and thus causing slow load times.

[image]

Comment: have you tried to use CURL ?

Comment: I don't see how js is going to make this faster. You should profile your program, measure how long each part takes. perhaps it's not the REST part, but the rest ;o)

Comment: What is "a long time"? are you sure it's not just the actual API you are calling that is slow to respond?

Comment: The time it takes for PHP to fetch the data from a remote URL is always going to be the slowest part of such a function by orders of magnitude (and can fail altogether if the network is down! You might want to look into implementing some error detection/recovery logic in here).  If the data you're processing doesn't change often then it may be worth caching it locally to reduce the number of HTTP requests you have to make.  Fetching it from a database or a file or memcache is going to be far faster than fetching it over the internet

Comment: Thanks for all your comments. I guess it is just fetching the URL that is slow to respond... I just wasn't sure as surely this cannot be a regular issue? But alas maybe it is. See screenshot of the Network tab in Chrome. On any other page (that isn't using the API) it loads instantly.